# Values not capture properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question related to the VBA.

- Problem

I have a code to do simple task but i don't what's the reason but sometimes this code works perfectly some time it's not.

- Code Explanation

Go to active sheets(un-hidden) sheets in the work book.

Search specific text in the assign column, in this case text is "Sum of Current Activity".

Copy the cell before the text.

Go to Reviewer sheet and find sheet name in the table.

Paste the copied cell as link value next to cell where we have sheet name in the table.

Continue the same process until all active sheets searched

CODE

```
Sub Sum of_Current_activity() 
Dim sht As Worksheet
Sheets("Reviewer Sheet").Select

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sht.Name <> "Reviewer Sheet" And Left(sht.Name, 1) = 0 Then

On Error Resume Next 
sht.Select

f2 = " Total"
£1 = ActiveSheet.Name & f2

Sheets(sht).Select
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Find(What:="Sum of Current Activity", _
After:=ActiveCell,_
LookIn:=xlValues,_
LookAt:=xlPart,_
SearchOrder:=xlByRows,_
SearchDirection:=x1Next,_
MatchCase:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Reviewer Sheet").Select 
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Find(What:=f1, _
After:=ActiveCell,_
LookIn:=xlValues,_
LookAt:=xlPart,_
SearchOrder:=xlByRows,_
SearchDirection:=xlNext,_
MatchCase:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Select 
ActiveSheet. Paste Link:=True

Else
End If 

Next sht

  End Sub
```

**P.S**, I have 10 different specific text to search in the 25 sheet. this code sometime works for all 10 texts and sometimes miss the values.

Comment: If you put [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3zX8.gif) at the top of the code sheet you will quickly find that you have used `£1` in `£1 = ActiveSheet.Name & f2` then tried to find `f1`.

Comment: Oh, it's a typo in the post, in the original code i use f1 not £1

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and try it again.

Comment: Also have `x1Next`

Answer (score 1):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
Sub Sum of_Current_activity() 
Dim sht As Worksheet, c1 As Range, c2 As range


For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name Like "0*" Then

        Set c1 = sht.Columns("J:J").Find(What:="Sum of Current Activity", _
                     LookIn:=xlValues,  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

        Set c2 = Sheets("Reviewer Sheet").Columns("C:C").Find( _
                 What:= sht.Name & " Total", _
                 LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) 

        If not c1 is nothing and not c2 is nothing then
            'edit: create link instead of copy value
            c2.offset(0, 14).Formula = _
              "='" & c1.parent.Name & "'!" & c1.offset(0,1).Address(true, true)

        End if


    End If    
Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: in this code how can i paste values as link , right now it paste as a value without link.

Comment: Hi Tim one issue in the code which i can't figure out how to resolve it. In Column J i have more-than one "Sum of Current Activity" code only copy the first but i want to copy the value next to second "Sum of Current Activity" in the column, Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

just because the task is simple, you could use `On Error Resume Next` statement and make a direct `Value` paste between ranges:

```
Sub main()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next ' prevent any subsequent 'Find()' method failure fro stopping the code
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If Left(sht.Name, 1) = "0" Then _
            Sheets("Reviewer Sheet").Columns("C:C").Find( _
                     What:=sht.Name & " Total", _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 14).Value = sht.Columns("J:J").Find(What:="Sum of Current Activity", _
                         LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

I once more stress that `On Error Resume Next` is here used only because it's a case where you can have a full control of its side effects that can arise from ignoring errors and go on

should you use this snippet in a bigger code, than *close* the snippet with `On Error GoTo 0` statement and resume default error handling before going on with some other code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! Specially for Tim Williams thank you so much.